# Putting a diagram in beamer

Tags: beamer, commutative-diagrams

I am having trouble putting a commutative diagram into a beamer presentation. I have tried using `\usepackage{amscd}` and `\usepackage{dicpic, pictecwd}` which work in latex but not in beamer.

Comment: Hi, welcome! `amscd` works fine in `beamer`, what did you try?

Comment: Try `tikz-cd` (better results anyway).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you've tried, but `amscd` works fine in `beamer`, e.g. (slightly modified from the first example in the manual)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amscd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
\begin{CD}
S^{{\mathcal{W}}_\Lambda}\otimes T
 @>j>>
 T\\
@VVV
 @VV{P}V\\
(S\otimes T)/I
 @=
 (Z\otimes T)/J
\end{CD}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`tikz-cd`, as Bernard mentioned, is a newer more powerful option. There is one thing to note when using with `beamer` though. `tikz-cd` uses a matrix to layout the elements of the diagram, and uses `&` by default as a column separator. This doesn't work in a default `beamer` frame, so you will need to make the frame `fragile`, or use `ampersand replacement`, for example like this (using a random example from the manual):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{ampersand replacement=\&}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi} \& B \arrow[red]{d}{\xi} \\
C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta} \& D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\&` instead of `&` to separate columns. The `fragile` version of the `frame` might look like this:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi} & B \arrow[red]{d}{\xi} \\
C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta} & D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
```

[image]